# Adding Cloud Firestore & Firebase to Flutter project (Android)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, dart, flutter

This is going to be a fairly long question, so I'll include a TL;DR at the end.

For days now, I've been trying to find a way to make my setup work, but to no avail. Now to make it complete and of aid to others, I'll be recording my steps here:

## Steps to reproduce

1. Create a new Flutter project (compiles and runs without any warnings)
2. Create a new Firebase console project
3. Follow [these instructions](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-firebase/#4) to add Firebase to android (also included below in case of version changes).
4. Add Cloud Firestore to the project in the pubspec.yaml
5. Encounter this error:

   - What went wrong:
     `Execution failed for task ':cloud_firestore:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.`

## Firebase instructions (as of now)

1. Install Google Repository (revision 58 currently) (not necessary anymore according to [this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15770), but done for verification).
2. Copy the package name found in `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`. In my case this was `com.omnisciamus.fire`. Use it to create a new android app in the Firebase project along with a debug key.
3. Drop the created `google-services.json` in `android/app`
4. Modify the `android/build.gradle` and `android/app/build.gradle`. I've changed this to using the latest versions (modifications included below).
5. At this point I reran the compilation to see if any issues popped up already, and we have 3 of these warnings, which is most likely the google services plugin, not something I can change anything about: 
   `registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)`
6. Now we add the dependencies in the pubspec.yaml, also included below.
   Now there are several possible versions we can use, but I first tried the latest versions (by including a `^` in front of the versions).

### Gradles

Changes to the `android/build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }

        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0' // upgraded from 3.0.1
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0' // added & upgraded from 3.1.1
        }
    }
```

And then we have the `android/app/build.gradle`:

```
//bottom of file
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

### Pubspec

The dependencies structure of my pubspec looks like this:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.0
  firebase_analytics: 0.3.0
  cloud_firestore: 0.3.1
```

### Setup details

For additional details I've included my flutter doctor -v output:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.1.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.309], locale en-GB)
    • Flutter version 0.1.5 at C:\Developer\Flutter\flutter
    • Framework revision 3ea4d06340 (5 weeks ago), 2018-02-22 11:12:39 -0800
    • Engine revision ead227f118
    • Dart version 2.0.0-dev.28.0.flutter-0b4f01f759

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 27.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Android
    • Android NDK at C:\Android\ndk-bundle
    • Platform android-P, build-tools 27.0.0
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:\Android
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-915-b01)

[√] Android Studio (version 3.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-915-b01)

[√] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2017.3)
    • Flutter plugin version 22.2.2
    • Dart plugin version 173.4548.30

[√] VS Code (version 1.21.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code
    • Dart Code extension version 2.10.0

[√] Connected devices (1 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 6.0 (API 23) (emulator)

• No issues found!
```

### Debug key

As this may become a tutorial I'll include a simple command to obtain the debug key (on Windows):
`cd %JAVA_HOME%\bin & keytool -exportcert -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore`

## TL;DR

Cloud_firestore crashes with a version of 0.3.x, how do you fix this?

Answer (score 3):

As I discussed this with a few co-developers, I discovered that one had found a working setup: changing the version of `cloud_firestore` to be below `0.3.0`, `0.2.9` for instance. According to [this recently published issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15972), the issue is that the 'stable' version of flutter doesn't have certain features that cloud_firestore uses, which causes the errors you see when compiling. I'll update the question in a while to reflect this answer if requested.

Comment: So did this solution work?   I ask because this solution does not look 100% similar to the instructions I see online.

Comment: It did work for me as well as some other devs, but perhaps some other things have changed by now (in the instructions perhaps)

Answer (score 2):

I solved my current **Cloud_Firestore** problems by:

- Changing the flutter channel from *beta* to *master*. Just run in the terminal `flutter channel master`. As proposed here [Cloud Firestore 0.3.2 - Execution failed for task ...](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15913)
- worked with flutter dependencies: `cloud_firestore: "^0.4.0"` even `cloud_firestore: "^0.3.2"`.

Hope this would help. I spent hours trying to figure it out why I could not compile my flutter app with cloud_firestore. I knew that the issue was around the flutter SDK versions, but I did not wanted to go for alpha. But the solution turned out to be as simple as using the master channel. Although, not sure yet what other issues may arise in the near future. However now, I can happily start testing with cloud firestore. ;)

Comment: Yeah I ran across the same solution in trying to fix this, (I spent *days* as well), but wanted to first find a solution where I didn't possibly have to break the rest of flutter by using the unstable version

Answer (score 0):

For the Firebase plugins to work with Swift you need to use newer versions:    But I am having android problems as well.  I also tried switching flutter channel from beta to dev.

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cloud_firestore: "^0.4.0"


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.0

dev_dependencies:
 flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  image_picker: 0.4.1
  #google_sign_in: '>=2.1.0 '
  google_sign_in: '3.0.0'
  #firebase_analytics: '>=0.2.3'
  firebase_auth: '>=0.4.5'
  #firebase_auth: '>=0.5.3'        #not working on android
  #firebase_database: '>=0.3.5'   #works on android
  firebase_database: '0.4.2'      #works on android
  #firebase_storage: '>=0.1.4'    #not Working on android
  #firebase_storage: '0.2.0'       #not working on android
```

Comment: I can't verify at the moment (don't have a mac at hand), but I'll verify it for andoid if I remember tomorrow. On the other hand, this specific 'question' was about adding firestore, which you don't seem to have included

Answer (score 0):

I also had similar issues while using firebase in flutter. I solved it by using this dependencies in my android/build.gradle file and remove any other existing dependencies.

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
```

and used this version for firestore and google in pubspec.yaml

```
cloud_firestore: 0.7.3
```

And if you have version related issues with any other firebase product then refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52886584/7727376)