# Gradle issue in flutter when using firebase

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, flutter

In my flutter application i am using firebase_auth for google_sign_in and it is working fine. But when i add cloud_firestore: to pubspec.yaml then get dependencies and then restart my app it show me an error like this:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-base is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.1,15.0.1]], but resolves to 16.0.1. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Finished with error: Gradle build failed: 1
```

Comment: These links should provide suggestions for workarounds https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bROui4ID9_Q&feature=youtu.be
 https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18579#issuecomment-398484148
    https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19868
    https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19983
    https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20486 I think there are some updates to plugins work-in-progress to fix these version conflicts.

Comment: I tried everything but nothing works for me!

Comment: Similar issue as:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53064229/flutter-build-errors-for-cloud-firestore-above-version-0-7-4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used this dependencies in my android/build.gradle file

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
```

and used this version for firebase and google in pubspec.yaml

```
firebase_auth: 0.5.11
google_sign_in: 3.0.4
cloud_firestore: 0.7.3
```

It works fine because at these versions gradle tooling was updated to match Android Studio 3.1.2.

Other firebase working versions:

```
firebase_admob: 0.5.5
firebase_analytic: 1.0.1
firebase_core: 0.2.4 
firebase_database: 1.0.1 
firebase_dynamic_links: 0.02
firebase_messaging: 1.0.2
firebase_performance: 0.0.3
firebase_remote_config: 0.0.4
firebase_storage: 0.3.7
```

Comment: Does not work if cloud_firestore version is above 0.7.3
ios Build ok but Android Build failed.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53064229/flutter-build-errors-for-cloud-firestore-above-version-0-7-4

Comment: @LiveRock, i know that's why i have given these working versions. This versions works because gradle tooling was updated at this versions. For reference refer [changelog](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cloud_firestore#-changelog-tab-).

Comment: I understand that the combination you gave works. But we need to move on to later version of the plugins because of bugs fixes etc.
That would be a more permanent solution. Any suggestions?

Comment: all this plugins are still in beta so wait for the initial version is the only suggestion i can give!

Answer (score 1):

This [link](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-firebase/#0) solved the issue for me.

First I set dependencies in my pubspec.yaml to

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cloud_firestore: ^0.8.2
```

and ran `flutter packages get` in my IDE's terminal.

Also I had to change the minimum target SDK version:

1. Open `android/app/build.gradle`, then find the line that says
   `minSdkVersion 16`.
2. Change that line to `minSdkVersion 21`.
3. Save the file.

Also, I had to open `android/app/build.gradle`, then add the following line as the last line in the file:
`apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`

Next, I had to open `android/build.gradle`, then inside the buildscript tag, add a new dependency:

```
buildscript {
   repositories {
       // ...
   }

   dependencies {
       // ...
       classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'   // new
   }
}
```

After this my app finally ran on the android emulator.

The [link](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-firebase/#6) has a more complete walkthrough if you get stuck.