# Flutter: Build errors for cloud_firestore: above version "0.7.4"

Tags: firebase, flutter, cloud, google-cloud-firestore

I have been trying to resolve a build issue for hours until I realise it is due to Flutter plugin cloud_firestore. Version 0.7.4 builds fine for both Android and iOS but anything above 0.7.4 like 0.8.2+1 will have errors such as:

> CloudFirestorePlugin.java:160: error: cannot find symbol
>           query = query.whereArrayContains(fieldName, value);
>                        ^   symbol:   method whereArrayContains(String,Object)   location: variable query of type
>   Query
>   /dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.8.2+1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/cloudfirestore/CloudFirestorePlugin.java:598:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>               builder.setTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled(
>                      ^   symbol:   method setTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled(Boolean)   location: variable builder
>   of type Builder
>   /dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.8.2+1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/cloudfirestore/CloudFirestorePlugin.java:678:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>           return FieldValue.arrayUnion(toArray(readValue(buffer)));
>                            ^   symbol:   method arrayUnion(Object[])   location: class FieldValue
>   /dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.8.2+1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/cloudfirestore/CloudFirestorePlugin.java:680:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>           return FieldValue.arrayRemove(toArray(readValue(buffer)));
>                            ^   symbol:   method arrayRemove(Object[])   location: class FieldValue Note:
>   /Users/peterlumdev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.8.2+1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/cloudfirestore/CloudFirestorePlugin.java
>   uses unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with
>   -Xlint:unchecked for details. 4 errors FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>   * What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':cloud_firestore:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>
> > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
> >     * Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> >     * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org BUILD FAILED in 11s Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I would like to use 0.8.2+1 cloud_firestore for both ios and Android because of the support of

```
await db.settings(timestampsInSnapshotsEnabled: true);
```

Appreciate some help here. Many Thanks!

Comment: Do you get errors on both Android and iOS?

Comment: I only got errors for Android.

Comment: I also got the same error for Android only. However, when I re-inserted google-services.json by Finder, the error disappeared.

Comment: I replaced the google-services.json file but still cannot build for Android:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':cloud_firestore:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for detail

Comment: Did not you put the files in Android Studio? It seems to be different from my case.

Comment: What do you mean by "Did not you put the files in Android Studio?"
Any specific directory you are referring to?

Comment: Dragging and dropping google-services.json file into the project on the side panel of Andoroid Studio when it puts in the corresponding path (yourproject/android/app/) causes an error.

Answer (score 1):

### There is a problem with google-services.json.

In my case, I was in the same situation while coding [Firebase for Flutter](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-firebase/#6) on Google Codelabs. I put GoogleService-Info.plist in Xcode in the corresponding folder and put google-services.json in the corresponding folder in Adndroid Studio as well. iOS Simulator worked, but in Android Studio the window like the one below is displayed, then pressing the OK button and launching Android Emulator resulted in the corresponding error.

#### When coding from scratch and inserting the google-services.json file from the Finder instead of Android Studio, no error occurred.

[image: Android Studio Window1]
[image: Android Studio Window2]

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because it is creating a gradle conflict. Version 0.7.3 of firestore is working because gradle tooling is updated at that version. Please refer [changelog](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cloud_firestore#-changelog-tab-) and also refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52886584/7727376) for any other working versions of firebase products.

Answer (score 1):

I feel you, I've also spent hours and hours trying to figure this out.

After building a SSCCE, and then applying the settings of that project to my project, and then some tweaking, I got my project working.

Although I adjusted more settings than I care to remember, these seem to have had the highest impact:

In `pubspec.yaml`:

```
# included two other common libraries others might use
cloud_firestore: 0.8.2+1
firebase_auth: 0.7.0
google_sign_in: 3.2.4
```

Explicitly disable these two features in `android/gradle.properties` :

```
android.useAndroidX=false
android.enableJetifier=false
```

Use these versions of dependencies in `android/build.grade`:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
}
```

And finally, use these settings in `android/app/build.gradle`:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
        ...
    }
    ...
}
...
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

It's also worth noting that I downloaded the `google-services.json` file again (though that didn't have any effect just by itself).

Any combination of these settings might help you.